# Timeout deploying node app to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I keep getting a timeout during compilation of the heroku node buildpack when installing `delayed-stream`. It get's to this part after about 1 minute and then hangs until the 15 minute timeout. Has anyone else seen this problem?

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
       npm WARN engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.24"})
       npm WARN engine boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.24"})
       npm WARN engine sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.24"})
       npm WARN engine hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.24"})
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/-/delayed-stream-0.0.5.tgz
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/-/delayed-stream-0.0.5.tgz


 !     Timed out compiling Node.js app (15 minutes)
 !     See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#time-limit
```

Comment: try npm cache clean and then run again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A third level dependency was including a module from git without https.

You can run `npm ls` to get the full dependency graph of all modules. To find bad deps using http instead of https you can use `npm ls | grep http://`.

Comment: I'm having this problem right now. Unfortunately, I don't understand your answer. How did you resolve the issue?

Comment: I found the nested dependency that was being included with http (from git). I had to fork every parent dependency in the tree down to the bad dependency and change to be dependent on my fork. E.g. repo looked like myPackage -> grandparent -> parent -> bad http dep. Created fork parent and grandparent. Updated parentFork to include the dep with https and grandparentFork to point to parentFork instead of parent. then updated my package.json to point to grandparentFork. now my deps look like myPackage -> grandparentFork -> parentFork -> https dep

Comment: Note that you should put in a full request to parent to fix the bad dependency. If it gets merged and published to npm you won't need your forks.

Comment: I guess my issue wasn't the same. I was using node to install cordova. It seems npm was failing because of the global (-g) param. I guess this may be to do with settings on my network. It worked fine without -g.